# How to handle invalid token "False" in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, odoo, postgresql-10

```
select replace(pol.bundle_product, '''', '"')::json ->> 'display_name' from pos_order_line pol where order_id in ('164568','140750');
```

i will query json data in postgresql but it shows error like this `invalid input syntax for type json Details: Token "False" is invalid. Where: JSON data, line 1: ..._name": "SDBF50DV-L Package", "product_merk": False...`
how to handle invalid json like that?

Comment: Could you share the entire json object? And why do you use the text function replace() on a piece of json? Or is this the issue and your input isn't (always?) valid json?

Comment: What is the data type of `pol.bundle_product`?

Comment: The only real solution is to fix it upstream.  Invalid JSON can be invalid in an infinite number of ways, are you going to play whack-a-mole with every one of them?

Comment: yes actually the data is invalid, there is a lot of data maybe around 30000. maybe the developer before me did this and I was told to do the fixing

Answer (score 2):

The issue it's that your bundle_product column value it's not a proper JSON value. That's why you are trying to replace single quotes with double quotes to convert it to a proper JSON value but seems that you are saving a Python dict converted as string but the boolean values aren't getting converted to JSON ones.

You need to save the result of json.dumps(dict_value) so you will be cover completely and you won't need to replace anything in your sql query. I was able to reproduce your issue.

I you wanna continue using your existing data you need to replace also `True` with `true`, `False` with `false` and also maybe `None` with `null`

Comment: yes actually the data is invalid, there is a lot of data maybe around 30000. maybe the developer before me did this and I was told to do the fixing. i don't know